# Multiply values within a column with a date range in R

Tags: r, date, product

I am very new to the forum and I hope the question is understandable.

I have a data frame (df) as follows

```
id     date         announcement_date  ret
12055  2001-08-02   2001-08-03         1.0246
12055  2001-08-03   2001-08-03         1.123
12055  2001-08-04   2001-08-03         0.994
11033  2001-08-02   2001-08-05         1.020
11033  2001-08-03   2001-08-05         0.997
11033  2001-08-04   2001-08-05         0.949
11033  2001-08-05   2001-08-05         1.048
11033  2001-08-06   2001-08-05         1.060
11033  2001-08-07   2001-08-05         1.002
```

How can I create a new column that includes the product of 'ret' grouped by id from announcement_date until the last existent day? That is, for id=11033 I would want to create a new column "Product" that looks like:

```
id     date         announcement_date  ret    Product
11033  2001-08-02   2001-08-05         1.020  -
11033  2001-08-03   2001-08-05         0.997  -
11033  2001-08-04   2001-08-05         0.949  -
11033  2001-08-05   2001-08-05         1.048  1.048
11033  2001-08-06   2001-08-05         1.060  1.048*1.060
11033  2001-08-07   2001-08-05         1.002  1.048*1.060*1.002
```

I tried the code

```
df$product <- aggregate(ret ~ id + ret, df, prod)
```

That works but I get the product of 'ret' for each 'id' over all dates, i.e. I don't know how to set the 'starting date' to announcement_date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(date>=announcement_date) %>% 
mutate(Product = accumulate(ret, `*`)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% right_join(df) %>% 
arrange(desc(id), date)
Joining, by = c("id", "date", "announcement_date", "ret")
     id       date announcement_date    ret  Product
1 12055 2001-08-02        2001-08-03 1.0246       NA
2 12055 2001-08-03        2001-08-03 1.1230 1.123000
3 12055 2001-08-04        2001-08-03 0.9940 1.116262
4 11033 2001-08-02        2001-08-05 1.0200       NA
5 11033 2001-08-03        2001-08-05 0.9970       NA
6 11033 2001-08-04        2001-08-05 0.9490       NA
7 11033 2001-08-05        2001-08-05 1.0480 1.048000
8 11033 2001-08-06        2001-08-05 1.0600 1.110880
9 11033 2001-08-07        2001-08-05 1.0020 1.113102
```

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely. How would you build in a date range? I tried filter(date>=announcement_date, date <=announcement_date + 45). Somehow the code ignores the upper bound though.

Comment: @hyun_12055, you can use between function: between(date, announcement_date, announcement_date <=45)

Comment: @hyun_12055, if my answer did work, can you please accept it by clicking the tick mark next to my answer.